# Message text truncated in WiX custom action

Tags: wix

I'm using the **Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session.Message** method to display a message to the user with a custom action using the following code:

```
var record = new Record();

record.FormatString = message;

session.Message(InstallMessage.Info| InstallMessage.User | (InstallMessage)MessageButtons.OK, record);
```

The message I'm trying to display is:

> Successfully installed the My Product Name to C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\My Company\My Product Name.You must now check the
>   ServiceHostWindowsService.exe.config file and update the configuration
>   for the specific installation, then start the My Product Name. You
>   should check the Windows Application Event Log to ensure all services
>   have started correctly.

But what's actually displayed is:

> Successfully installed the My Product Name to ...\.You must now check
>   the ServiceHostWindowsService.exe.config file and update the
>   configuration for the specific installation, then start the My Product
>   Name. You should check the Windows Application Event Log to ensure all
>   services have start...

Can someone please explain why the text is getting truncated to 254 chars? Is this a known limit? If so, can you point me at the documentation? Is there anyway to display a longer message?

Thanks in advance,

Carl.

Answer (score 0):

If the text extends beyond the control's margins, it is clipped and an ellipsis ("...") is inserted.
You can exchange the text control with a ScrollableText control in the ErrorDlg or resize the text control there.